# If $\alpha:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function and injective $\Longrightarrow $ $\text{int}(\alpha([a,b]))=\emptyset\;$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

If $\alpha:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuous function and injective, $n>1$

We can say that   $\text{int}(\alpha([a,b]))=\emptyset$ ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you assume that $n>1$?

Comment: Show: if there is an interior point in the image, then the inverse of $\alpha$ would be continuous on a disk centered there.  This is called "invariance of domain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if $\alpha $ is continuous then $\alpha[a,b] $ is a measure zero set hence has empty interior.

Comment: Why $\alpha[a,b]$ has measure $0$?
Thanks.

Comment: @GastónBurrull Because $ \alpha[a,b]) $ is a 1-dimentional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n $

Comment: I can't see it. Do you need some fact for homeomorphisms and measure? I know that each point has a neigborhood wich restricted to the set is homeomorphic to a segment and segment has measure 0 (is true that homeomorphisms sends measure 0 sets into measure 0 sets?). I think Lindelof property for R^n allows us to conclude.

Comment: @GastónBurrull This is an obvious enough statement if you are familiar with behavior of Hausdorff measures with dimentions. Otherwise you can always go for approximation by cubes or rectangles to get estimate on its outer measure.